# SQL rebuild Index Maintenance Plan is missing the Index Stat Option to set fragmentation percentages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-indexes, maintenance-plan

My maintenance plan is missing the section in the config window that allows you to set the fragmentation > a percentage. Does anyone know how to get this option or is it maybe I'm on too old a version of SQL? I'm on SQL 2014.

[image]

Comment: If you have SQL Server Agent, I'd recommend using the [Ola Hallengren Index Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/) stored procedure and jobs, they're pretty much considered the industry standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed a different version of SQL Server.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What version of SQL Server did you need? Without that information, this isn’t a very useful answer.